# Google Analytics with Swift 3 iOS 9

Tags: ios, xcode, google-analytics, swift3, ios9

I tried to find informations about how to use Google Analytics with Swift 3, and even if it looks like some people succeeded, I can't make it work myself.

The Google Analytics documentation doesn't help, it's only for working for Swift 2.

I used the pod "Google/Analytics" in version 3.17.0 and tried to add this line inside a bridging header file as some people mentioned :

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
```

But I got an error about Xcode complaining that bridging headers doesn't work with Swift 3.

Then I tried to add the same line inside the .h as another post suggest, but doesn't work neither, Xcode complains "Include of non-modular header inside framework module XXX".

I tried to set "Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules to YES but it doesn't change anything, still got the same error.

Last thing I tried is to add :

```
import Google
```

Inside the file where I use Google Analytics, but now GAI is not recognized.

```
// Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
var configureError: NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

// Optional: configure GAI options.
guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
    assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
}
gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.verbose  // remove before app release
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: imo, you've done your due diligence, somethings amuck with the framework. Consider submitting a bug to google?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Follow these steps in order to configure Google Analytics

1. Create a project on Google Analytics and download the configuration file  **"GoogleService-Info.plist"**.
2. install the Google Analytics to you project using pods *(make sure know error is shown in the terminal)*.
3. Clear and close your project and then navigate to you project folder and open " **XXX.xcworkspace** " instead of "**XXX.xcodeproj**".
4. Then add the "**GoogleService-Info.plist**" to your project (check copy if need option).
5. Create a Bridging file in your project if there is already one exists then no need to recreate it.

   5.1. To create a bridging file the easiest way is to add/create new objective-c class to the project and the option pops up which ask you to create a bridging file and it sets all of the setting by default.
6. Open the Bridging file normally named as "**YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h**" and copy this in it     `" #import <Google/Analytics.h> "`
7. Open "**AppDelegate.swift**" and copy and paste the below code in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** for setting the Analytics tracker

   > ```
   > // Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
   > var configureError: NSError?
   > GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
   > assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
   >
   > // Optional: configure GAI options.
   > guard let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() else {
   >   assert(false, "Google Analytics not configured correctly")
   > }
   > gai.trackUncaughtExceptions = true  // report uncaught exceptions
   > gai.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.verbose  // remove before app release
   > ```
8. Build your project.

I hope it works if there is any problem then let me know.

Comment: I found why It wasn't working before, I was trying to use it inside a framework and not a "final" target, so I had to implement GAI inside the final product and extend a class to use it inside the framework (which is the shared part of my app).
Thank you !

Comment: Is there a way to use it without the bridging header but using a module import directly in the swift class?

Comment: Why Google can't support their own product properly? The Official instruction just misleading everyone who has to keep using Google Analytics.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift It never mentions we need this plist file. But, actually, we need it.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I could not import the "Google/Analytics.h" header as Xcode generate error. Because "Google/Analytics.h" header is not available in the 'GoogleAnalytics sdk' as mentioned in Google's Official page.
So, i just used following line in AppDelegete.m file

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "GAI.h"
```

Hope it will work just fine. Environment Xcode: 8.2 iOS :10.2

Comment: It looks like you're using Obj-C so I think the issue I was facing is different since I'm using Swift 3. Sometimes importing Obj-C librairies can be a real pain.